# Two past tense verb in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Does the sentence, "Did you just assumed that it is a stick?", shows grammatical correctness? I am looking for answers and I am not sure if the given sentence is correct with regards to the use of two past tense verbs.

Comment: This is one of the most common errors we see English learners make, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **NO**.

This is a very basic grammar rule, you should use a bare infinitival(or the `plain` form of) verb after the auxiliary do. You don't have to inflect the form of the main verb because *"did"* already indicate the tense, which is past tense.

However, sometimes *do* functions as a lexical verb, for example, in a cleft sentence

> What I did *was* . . .

You are allowed to use the past tense form of verb(was) because *did* is a lexical. But that's a different case, I wouldn't explain it here.